# How to download Flash Player for Opera Browser Debian 10? Step by Step

Tags: linux, terminal, flash, opera

I've been searching for many days now and I still cannot get flash on Opera Browser for my Linux Debian 10 Chromebook. Can someone please help me? I've tried methods with Terminal but most of the methods I've used are outdated due to flash player site being 'End Of Life' no longer letting me download plugins!

Comment: Sorry but I have to ask - what do you need Flash player for these days?

Comment: Unfortunately, flash is pretty much gone. Adobe did not simply stop updating it, they killed it. And just about every browser followed by taking steps end-users could not keep it alive in their browsers or had to work very hard to keep it. _Stops here without going on a rant about it._

Answer (score 1):

Flash is EOL. You are unlikely to find Adobe's version available anywhere, and even if you do it had a kill-switch to stop it bring used after the death date. You might find a third party reimplementation of Flash, and here are some suggestions that may or may not be Linux-friendly,

> One effort to preserve, or reimplement Flash was the Gnash project, an open-source Flash alternative that lived under the Free Software Foundation banner. “Unfortunately, Gnash soon fell behind Adobe’s player in terms of features,” Alessandro Pignotti,  founder and CTO of Leaning Technologies, a compile-to-JavaScript and compile-to-WebAssembly tools provider, and author of the open-source Flash player Lightspark, wrote in a post.

> Other efforts, in addition to Linstedt’s petition to open-source Flash, include Shumway, an HTML5 technology experiment; Ruffle, a Flash Player emulator written in Rust; and Lightspark, a C++ implementation of the Flash player,

Quoted verbatim from https://sdtimes.com/webdev/saving-flash-from-extinction/